# Prefetching $templateCache

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, caching

My angularjs application basically loads in 4 steps:

- main HTML
- all scripts and CSS files
- `$templateCache`, let's call it `template.html`
- images

I guess, I should bypass the `$templateCache` when loading the starting page. But for now, I'd like to start fetching `template.html` ASAP, i.e., at the same time as the scripts get loaded.

The possibly relevant piece of my code looks like

```
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/.../angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='/my.js'></script>
<link href='/my.css' media='all' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

Here, `my.js` contains all my scripts and gets loaded at the same time as angular. Is there something allowing me to fetch `template.html` in the same way, so it gets put into the browser's cache?

### Update

I've tried two prefetching possibilities, both failed:

```
<link href="template.html" rel="prefetch"/>
```

and

```
<iframe class=invisible src="template.html"></iframe>
```

The first gets cancelled and the second comes too late to be effective.

Comment: One option is to convert the html into javascript that add the template into `$templateCache` directly. If you are using Grunt, or would like to use, See https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates, this task will to the conversion for you.

Comment: @runTarm I'm actually doing it all manually. I guess creating `template.js` should be no harder than creating `template.html` was, I just don't know how it should look like.

Comment: Have a look at that grunt plugin, there is an example generated output, you could start from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the HTML can't be fetch soon enough, the whole [script directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) is completely pointless.

According to runTarm's suggestion, I ended up generating the Javascript instead. All it takes is

```
.factory('$templateCache', function($cacheFactory, $http, $injector) {
    var cache = $cacheFactory('templates');
    cache.put("MY_PAGE_1", "ESCAPED_TEXT_1");
    cache.put("MY_PAGE_2", "ESCAPED_TEXT_2");
    ...
    return {
        get: function(url) {
            var fromCache = cache.get(url);
            return fromCache ? fromCache : $http.get(url);
        }
    };
}
```

In the escaped text you must honor the 1024 string-literal length limit and escape newlines and double quotes. That's all.